# Javascript matrix code not working

Tags: javascript, rotation

I am trying to implement the arbitrary rotation matrix in JS code, but I end up with the wrong value.

[image]

```js
function dotProduct(v1, v2) {
  return Math.round(v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2]);
}

function matrixMultiply(matrix, v) {
  return [dotProduct(matrix[0], v), dotProduct(matrix[1], v), dotProduct(matrix[2], v)];
}

function toRadians(angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function aRotate(p, v, a) {
  var ca = Math.cos(a),
    sa = Math.sin(a);
  var r = [
    [ca + v[0] * v[0] * (1 - ca), v[0] * v[1] * (1 - ca) - v[2] * sa, v[0] * v[2] * (1 - ca) + v[1] * sa],
    [v[0] * v[1] * (1 - ca) + v[2] * sa, ca + v[1] * v[1] * (1 - ca), v[1] * v[2] * (1 - ca) - v[0] * sa],
    [v[2] * v[0] * (1 - ca) - v[1] * sa, v[2] * v[1] * (1 - ca) + v[0] * sa, ca + v[2] * v[2] * (1 - ca)]
  ];
  return matrixMultiply(r, p);
}

var p = aRotate([100, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100], toRadians(90));
console.log(p);
```

I am rotating the point `(100,0,0)` around the axis `(0,0,100)` over `90` degrees. I expect to get `(0,100,0)`, but I get `(0,10000,0)`.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should normalize `v` first!

Comment: Plus why aren't you using object like `{x: x, y: y, z: z}`? That would be clear!

Comment: thanks, I forgot to normalize `v` lol.

Comment: Useful article: [Matrix math for the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Matrix_math_for_the_web). You might want to use 4x4 matrices, those can be directly applied to CSS.